# how to check non-empty selection?

Tags: python

I am using plotly-dash dropdown menu with multiple selection enabled. so the dropdown menu returned either an empty list when no selection, or a string ( with one selection) or list of strings ( with multiple selection).

How do I check if returned is not empty?

if I use below, it doesn't work for empty list

```
if selection is not None:
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is checking the length of the list not working? If the selection does not have a length of 0, then it is not empty, right?

Comment: thanks, but what happen if returned is a string?

Comment: use len() or use default like if selection != [ ]:

Comment: @roudan Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```py
def check_selection(selection):
    if selection:
        if isinstance(selection, list):
            return "Multiple Selections"
        else:
            return "One Selection"
    else:
        return "No Selection"
```

Empty sequences (like strings and lists) are considered "falsy" in Python, and evaluate to the boolean `False`. Please let me know if I interpreted your question correctly, and this answer helps.

Comment: I'd greatly appreciate if you could please accept my answer by click the checkmark on the left side of the answer @roudan

Comment: yes I just did, I have to wait for 4 minutes before I can accept the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Empty list is not same as `None`. You can check length of the list using `len()` function. If length is 0, the list is empty.

Try it:

```py
if len(selection) == 0:
    #code if the list is empty
else:
    #code if list is not empty
```

The code will also work for string, because as per question if single selection is made, the menu will return a string(which will have some length). We can check in else part of the code as if it is a string or list using `type()` function.

```py
rlist = [1, 2, 3]
rstring = 'test'
def test_selection(obj):
    if len(obj) == 0:
        print('empty')
    else:
        if type(obj) is str:
            print('str object')
        else:
            print('list')

test_selection(rlist) #output :- list
test_selection(rstring) #output :-  str object
test_selection([])  #output :-  empty
```